# Python pandas calculate the percentage of the total

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For each row, how to get a percentage of the total num? Below is my Python pandas output

sample data

```
    vehicle_make    Num
0   Acura           2
1   Audi            3
2   BMW             7
3   Buick           6
```

expected result

```
    vehicle_make    Num   percent
0   Acura           2       11.1%
1   Audi            3       16.7%
2   BMW             7       38.9%
3   Buick           6       33.3%
```

Comment: `df['percentage'] = df['Num'] / df['Num'].sum()` ?

Comment: `df['PCT']=(df.Num/df.Num.sum()).mul(100).round(2).astype(str)+'%'`

Comment: Wen's work perfectly, thanks